# I created many sprites with the same name and when doing anything with all of the sprites it only affects the last created sprite

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite

I am making a game which is like simplified civ 5 and it creates a fog on every tile with a for range function thus all fog tiles have the same name. So when I test if a unit sees the fog and thus removes the fog it only uses the last created fog tile because they all have the same name. So how could I affect all the sprites named "Cloud" at the same time?

I've tried to just check if the x and y of a Cloud sprite are within the sight radius of a unit.

Here's the entire code, the `"checkforfog"` function is what checks what I just explained

```
import pygame
from threading import Thread
import random
from random import randint
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import os
import sys
pygame.font.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 150, 0)
blue = (30, 144, 255)
light_blue = (40, 191, 255)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
walk_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("walk.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.load("music.wav")
walk_sound.set_volume(10)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
numlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
font1 = pygame.font.Font('celtic.ttf', 25)
font2 = pygame.font.Font('celtic.ttf', 45)

turnnum = 0
starter = 0
mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
buildtabnum = 0
bvar = 1
gold = 100
food = 10
iron = 0
#------------------------------------------------------------------

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dist = ((x1-x2) ** 2 + (y1-y2) ** 2) ** 0.5
    return (dist)

def myround(x, base = 64):
    return base * round(x/base)

def randomlandtile():
    if random.choice(numlist) > 3:
        return random.choice(landtilelist)
    else:
        return oceantile

def randomoceantile():
    if random.choice(numlist) > 1:
        return oceantile
    else:
        return grasstile

def text(font, msg, color, x, y):
    screen_text = (font).render(msg, True, color)
    screen.blit(screen_text, [x, y])

def start(w, h, x, y, msgx, msgy):
    img = pygame.image.load("StartScreen.png")
    dark = pygame.image.load("DarkBuildTab.png")
    bright = pygame.image.load("BrightBuildTab.png")
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
    global starter
    if mouse[0] < (x + w) and mouse[0] > x and mouse[1] < (y + h) and mouse[1] > y:
        screen.blit(bright, (x, y))
        if click[0] == 1:
            starter += 1
    else:
        screen.blit(dark, (x, y))
    text(font2, "Play", black, msgx, msgy)

def resource(msg, icon, x, y, msgx, msgy):
    img = pygame.image.load(icon)
    screen.blit(img, (x, y))
    text(font1, msg, white, msgx, msgy)

def resourcetab():
    top = pygame.image.load("TopBar.png")
    screen.blit(top, (0, 0))
    resource(str(food), "FoodIcon.png", 150, 0, 185, 0)
    resource(str(gold), "GoldIcon.png", 0, 0, 35, 0)
    resource(str(iron), "IronIcon.png", 300, 0, 335, 0)

def build(msg, w, h, x, y, bimg):
    global bvar
    dark = pygame.image.load("BuildTab1.png")
    bright = pygame.image.load("BuildTab2.png")
    buildimg = pygame.image.load(bimg)
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if mouse[0] < (x + w) and mouse[0] > x and mouse[1] < (y + h) and mouse[1] > y:
        screen.blit(bright, (x, y))
        if click[0] == 1 and bvar == 1:
            town1 = town(green, 64, 64)
            town1.rect.x = testunit.rect.x
            town1.rect.y = testunit.rect.y
            town_list.add(town1)
            bvar = 0
            print (town_list)
    else:
        screen.blit(dark, (x, y))
        bvar = 1
    screen.blit(buildimg, ((x + 200, y)))
    text(font2, msg, black, (x + 35), (y + 18))

def buildtab(w, h, x, y, msgx, msgy):
    global buildtabnum
    dark = pygame.image.load("DarkBuildTab.png")
    bright = pygame.image.load("BrightBuildTab.png")
    img = pygame.image.load("BuildTab.png")
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if buildtabnum == 1:
        screen.blit(img, (x, (y + h)))
    if mouse[0] < (x + w) and mouse[0] > x and mouse[1] < (y + h) and mouse[1] > y:
        screen.blit(bright, (x, y))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and buildtabnum == 0:
                print ("click")
                buildtabnum = 1
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print ("click")
                buildtabnum = 0
    else:
        screen.blit(dark, (x, y))
    text(font2, "Build Menu", black, msgx, msgy)

def turnbutton(w, h, x, y, msgx, msgy):
    dark = pygame.image.load("DarkTurnButton.png")
    bright = pygame.image.load("BrightTurnButton.png")
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if mouse[0] < (x + w) and mouse[0] > x and mouse[1] < (y + h) and mouse[1] > y:
        screen.blit(bright, (x, y))
        if click[0] == 1:
            if testunit.movement <= 0:
                global turnnum
                turnnum += 1
                testunit.movement += 1
                testbarb.movement += 1
                testbbarb.movement += 1
    else:
        screen.blit(dark, (x, y))
    text(font2, "Next Turn", black, msgx, msgy)

def testformove(self):
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if self.rect.collidepoint(pos) and click[0] == 1:
        self.select = 1
        #self.imgchange()

def checkforfog(self):
    x = self.rect.x
    y = self.rect.y
    print (distance(Cloud.rect.x, Cloud.rect.y, x, y))
    if distance(Cloud.rect.x, Cloud.rect.y, x, y) >= (self.sight * 64):
        for Cloud in cloud_list():
            cloud_list.remove(Cloud)
    if not distance(Cloud.rect.x, Cloud.rect.y, x, y) >= (self.sight * 64):
        cloud_list.draw(screen)

def move(self):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    global mx
    global my
    global lol
    self.rect.x = myround(mx-32)
    self.rect.y = myround(my-32)
    dx,dy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    cx,cy = self.rect.center
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if mouse[0] < (860 + 230) and mouse[0] > 860 and mouse[1] < (1000 + 60) and mouse[1] > 1000:
        pass
    elif click[0] == 1 and self.movement >= 1 and self.select == 1:
        if distance(cx, cy, dx, dy) <= (self.moverange * 64 + 32) and distance(cx, cy, dx, dy) >= 64:
            if Tile.rect.collidepoint(mouse):
                print (type(Tile))
                mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                self.movement -= 1
                pygame.mixer.Sound.play(walk_sound)

def airandom(self):
    num = random.randrange(64, ((self.moverange + 1) * 64), 64)
    movelist = [(num) * -1, (num)]
    return (random.choice(movelist))

def aimove(self):
    if testunit.movement == 0 and self.movement >= 1:
        self.rect.y += airandom(self)
        self.rect.x += airandom(self)
        self.movement -= 1

def main():
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    while starter == 0:
        print 
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        #print (event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        clock.tick(30)
        start(300, 80, 800, 550, 850, 568)
        pygame.display.flip()
    while starter == 1:
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
        town_list.draw(screen)
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        #print (event)
        checkforfog(testunit)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        turnbutton(230, 60, 860, 1000, 870, 1008)
        buildtab(300, 80, 100, 100, 130, 118)
        if buildtabnum == 1:
            build("Town", 200, 80, 100, 180, "Town1.png")
        resourcetab()
        pygame.display.flip()
        allies = ally_list.sprites()
        for pygame.sprite in allies:
            testformove(pygame.sprite)

        for pygame.sprite in allies:
            move(pygame.sprite)
            pygame.sprite.update

        aimove(testbarb)
        aimove(testbbarb)
        clock.tick(30)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

class spearman(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height, m, r):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Spearman.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.movement = m
        self.moverange = r
        self.select = 0
        self.sight = 2

        def imgchange(self):
            self.image = pygame.image.load("SpearmanGlow").convert_alpha()

class barbarian(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height, m, r):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Barbarian.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.movement = m
        self.moverange = r

class bossbarbarian(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height, m, r):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("BossBarbarian.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.movement = m
        self.moverange = r

class grasstile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Grass.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.fog = 1

class oceantile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Ocean.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.fog = 1

class mountaintile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Mountain.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.fog = 1

class cloud(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Fog.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class town(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Town1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class mine(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Mine.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

landtilelist = [grasstile, grasstile, grasstile, grasstile, grasstile, grasstile, grasstile, mountaintile]
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
ally_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
town_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
cloud_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
for row in range(0, 17):
    for col in range(0, 30):
        if row > 4 and row < 12 and col > 10 and col < 20:
            Tile = randomlandtile()(red, 64, 64)
        else:
            Tile = randomoceantile()(red, 64, 64)
        Tile.rect.x = col * 64
        Tile.rect.y = row * 64
        all_sprites_list.add(Tile)

for row in range(0, 17):
    for col in range(0, 30):
        if row > 4 and row < 12 and col > 10 and col < 20:
            Cloud = cloud(red, 64, 64)
        else:
            Cloud = cloud(red, 64, 64)
        Cloud.rect.x = col * 64
        Cloud.rect.y = row * 64
        cloud_list.add(Cloud)

testunit = spearman(red, 64, 64, 1, 2)
testunit.rect.x = 640
testunit.rect.y = 640
testbarb = barbarian(red, 64, 64, 1, 1)
testbarb.rect.x = 960
testbarb.rect.y = 704
testbbarb = bossbarbarian(red, 64, 64, 1, 2)
testbbarb.rect.x = 960
testbbarb.rect.y = 640
all_sprites_list.add(testunit)
all_sprites_list.add(testbarb)
all_sprites_list.add(testbbarb)
enemy_list.add(testbarb)
enemy_list.add(testbbarb)
ally_list.add(testunit)
all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
event = pygame.event.poll()

print (event)

main()
```

I expected the `"checkforfog"` function to check for all Cloud sprites, but it only checks the last created Cloud sprite.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue. I would wagger a guess that nobody wants to sift through 19 pages of code for what seems to be an design issue.

Comment: You need to iterate over the cloud_list group to edit a specific cloud object. Cloud.rect.x, Cloud.rect.y, x, y is referring to the Cloud class not the an instance of the Cloud class. Example: for cloud in cloud_list: #modify each cloud here. Also, your cloud class is lower case but you refer to it in upper case?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def checkforfog():

    for cloud in cloud_list:

        print (distance(cloud.rect.x, cloud.rect.y, other_cloud.x, other_cloud.y))

        if distance(cloud.rect.x, cloud.rect.y, other_cloud.x, other_cloud.y) >= (sight * 64):

            cloud_list.remove(cloud)

        elif not distance(cloud.rect.x, cloud.rect.y, other_cloud.x, other_cloud.y) >= (sight * 64):

            cloud_list.draw(screen)
```

Note this code I posted is only a general idea as I don't believe you posted everything and some of it is unclear, so take it as a guide. But as you can see, I iterate over the cloud_list to access each cloud individually.

Comment: What do you mean I could have left something out?